# 7zip - extract with specific structure and specific folder

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have a zip file that people are going to upload. The structure looks like this:

```
file.zip
    \a bunch of directories: 
    web\ws2go-data\
    web\ws2go-data\project\
    web\ws2go-data\project\projectname\dir1
    web\ws2go-data\project\projectname\dir2
```

I want to copy this into a specific folder - let's say
C:\projects\projectname

but I don't want all the hierarchy

ex:

don't want: C:\projects\projectsname\web\ws2go-data\project\projectname

do want:  C:\projects\projectsname\dir1

do want:  C:\projects\projectsname\dir2

So far, I have something like this

```
cd C:\projects
7z x zip-test.zip -otest1 web/ws2go-data/project/projectname
```

But it gives me what I don't want. I can't figure out how to remove all the above folder structure.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not create a zip file with the proper directory hierarchy? (Unpacking that file.zip, moving the stuff to proper locations, creating a new file.zip from the cleaned up hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the 'e' flag with 7zip, it will extract everything to the current folder (or you can use -o to specify the folder):

```
cd C:\projects  
7z e zip-test.zip
```

or:

```
7z e zip-test.zip -oC:\projects
```

from: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm

Comment: problem it doesn't keep any hierarchy structure of the the directories of the structure I have. dir1 and dir 2 have many files and many sub folders.

Comment: gotcha, then what does this give you: 7z x zip-test.zip web\ws2go-data\project -oC:\projects

Comment: it works for me, but it retains higher directory structure, i.e. if I have archive with a/b/c structure and d1 with d2 inside c, using "7z x foo.zip a/b/c/d1 -oc:\foo" will extract only single directory, but it will extract it to c:\foo\a\b\c\d1. Still, thanks for that, it helps a lot!

Comment: If folder is: "pro.jects" you need use this: 7z e zip-test.zip -o"C:\pro.jects"